# Is there an example OAuth2 client module anywhere?

Tags: services, authentication-authorization

Similar to [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/738) and [this request](http://drupal.org/node/1307638), I'm creating a OAuth client in Drupal 7 but using OAuth2.0. There's an [OAuth2 module](http://drupal.org/project/oauth2) with an [unpublished Drupal 7 version](http://drupalcode.org/project/oauth2.git/tree/c902ae6627b7426a945c3b37af1d5a9bea999f12) that I've toyed with, but it's geared pretty exclusively for servers or proxies, not clients. I've started writing a skeleton module for an OAuth2 client implementation, but before I go any further I wanted to make sure I'm not just spinning my wheels. Are there are any good modules that either implement a web services client using the OAuth2 standard, or a template module that I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

A year later, there is [OAuth2 Server](http://drupal.org/project/oauth2_server) which provides the server part only, but has tests which are a good demonstration of client code in Drupal (using drupal_http_request()), so that code can at least be used as an example.
The [module documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1958718) also tries to explain basic OAuth2 concepts and potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Several months later from [OAuth2 Server](http://drupal.org/project/oauth2_server) I still couldn't find any suitable OAuth2 Client (especially one that works with OAuth2 Server). So I developed an [OAuth2 Client](https://github.com/dashohoxha/oauth2_client) myself.

It is also on drupal.org, but it is a sandbox and needs some review and support in order to be promoted as a full project: https://drupal.org/node/2138549

Comment: Looks like it's there now: https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth2_client

Comment: That's right, now it is a full Drupal project. It is just an oauth2 client not a web services client (it just returns an oauth2 token). However it can be used with the module "Web service client" (https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient). See this make file for the patches that are required: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/btrclient/tree/btrClient.make#n11

Comment: How about [Web Service Clients](https://www.drupal.org/project/clients) (the "clients" module)?  I need to use that one because it's a dependency for the [Remote Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/remote_entity).

I really wish those two didn't have the same name.

Comment: I haven't used this module before, I didn't know about it. Maybe it is better than the module wsclient and I feel sorry that I didn't find out about it before. If you want to use it with ouath2 then you will have to make a patch for it (similar to what I have done for wsclient). I think that it should not be very difficult.

Comment: Thanks.  I just added a comparison page for all of those modules.  There's actually 3!  [Comparison of Web-service client modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2292623)